# How to change the Default Number Format for a Calc Spreadsheet?

Tags: libreoffice, language-support

I have Calc spreadsheets which are  by default in the French number format. I have no idea how this came about except that I live in France and the second language on my laptop is French. In system settings/Language Support, Language and Regional Formats I have English UK. On changing the number format for all cells in the Calc Spreadsheet I can work in English but each time I save and close the file it reverts to French. I have also tried to save the re-formatted number format file as another name but the same thing happens, it reverts to the Default French when I close and reopen it.
I built this spreadsheet years ago and it is quite complex so I would prefer being able to revert it to its' original English number format. 
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you please open a terminal window, run the `locale` command, and show us the output by editing your question.

Comment: I've found the solution!! I was saving the file in the original .xlsx format as I imported it from my OSX days. Now that for the first time I've saved it as an .ods file the again corrected number format, has stuck.

Comment: bob@bob-ThinkPad-W530:~$ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
bob@bob-ThinkPad-W530:~$ ^C

Comment: Ok, good. Can you please submit that as an answer (it's perfectly fine to answer your own question). Then, in a couple of days, you'll be able to accept the answer to mark the problem as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution!! I was saving the file in the original .xlsx format as I imported it from my OSX days. Now that for the first time I've saved it as an .ods file the again corrected number format, has stuck.